# ¿Cómo hacer para que me de como número el id del tr con createElement?

Tags: javascript

Al plasmar el `tr` en la consola no me pasa como número, me pasa como texto completo así: `"C_${item.id}")` y necesito q me muestre `id="C_15"`, adjunto código:

```
carrito.map(item => {

const tr = document.createElement('tr')
tr.classList.add('ItemCarrito')
tr.setAttribute("id", "C_${item.id}")
```

Comment: Tienes que usar backslash, no comillas:  ```C_${item.id}```

Comment: Cuando vas a concatenar variables con los símbolos `${...}`, la cadena (incluida la variable) deben estar encerrados en *comillas invertidas*, por lo que debería ser algo así: ` C_${item.id} `.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que usar [Plantillas Literales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#) en este caso, no comillas normales. Está explicado claramente en la documentación:

> Las plantillas literales se delimitan con el caracter de comillas o
> tildes invertidas (` `) (grave accent), en lugar de las comillas
> sencillas o dobles.
>
> Las plantillas de cadena de caracteres pueden contener marcadores,
> identificados por el signo de dólar y envueltos en llaves
> (`${expresión}`). Las expresiones contenidas en los marcadores, junto
> con el texto entre ellas, son enviados como argumentos a una función.
>
> La función por defecto sencillamente concatena las partes para formar
> una única cadena de caracteres. Si hay una expresión antes de la
> plantilla literal (aquí indicada mediante etiqueta), se le conoce como
> "plantilla etiquetada". En este caso, la expresión de etiqueta
> (típicamente una función) es llamada con la plantilla literal como
> parámetro, que luego puede ser manipulada antes de ser devuelta.
>
> En caso de querer escapar una comilla o tilde invertida en una
> plantilla literal, se debe poner una barra invertida (`\`) antes de la
> comilla o tilde invertida.

Así debería funcionar, salvo otros errores:

```
tr.setAttribute("id", `C_${item.id}`)
```

Te dejo unos ejemplos hechos a mano, en el segundo console podrás ver que se usan sólo dos tildes invertidas (una de apertura y otra de cierre) aunque vayas a incluir varios valores en el resultado final, como es natural, debes usar `${expresion}  por cada expresión:

```js
var item = {id:7, name:'Siete'};

console.log(`C_${item.id}`);
console.log(`Id: ${item.id} \t Name: ${item.name}`);
```